# Problems using App Gateway as Origin with Azure Frontdoor Premium (Preview)

Tags: azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door

I am trying to deploy n Azure Frontdoor Premium Resource (preview) with application gateway as the origin, it will send traffic to app gateway via the private link service, however I am facing this blocker as shown in the image below, my question is

Specifically to app gateway what does target sub resource mean? I understand from Microsoft docs that with app resource as origin you could leave it blank.

also note if i click target sub resource it shows no available items.

[image]

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this feature is not supported in azure as Private Link is in private preview on Application Gateway. At present, Private Link Service is only supported on Standard Load Balancer. Hence, sending traffic to App gateway via Private link service is not possible without getting onboarded to the Private preview feature via a Microsoft support request.

I had also tried deploying Azure Frontdoor Premium Resource (preview) with application gateway as the origin no available item is showing in Target Resource.

[image]

> Azure Front Door Standard/Premium (Preview) is currently in public
> preview. This preview version is provided without a service level
> agreement, and it's not recommended for production workloads. Certain
> features might not be supported or might have constrained
> capabilities. For more information, [see Supplemental Terms of Use for
> Microsoft Azure Previews](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/preview-supplemental-terms/)

However, if needed found one template which is created by community team to create Front Door Standard/Premium with Application Gateway origin:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/templates/front-door-standard-premium-application-gateway-public/ by providing the host name only and uses an NSG and WAF policy to validate that traffic has come through the Front Door origin.

Comment: thank you for your helpful reply, does that mean if I am onboarded to the feature something should show up in the target sub resource? secondly what is expected to show at the target sub resource? for example with the storage as origin the target sub resource is a blob or file.

Comment: as mentioned earlier Private link for Application Gateway is in Private preview, so I am not pretty sure what sub resource it would generate. Currently for few Origin type it showing eg; app service, Storage. Will get back here once i get update on application gateway.

Comment: I triggered an email to production group team for the update, once i get response , i will update here.

Comment: Since we follow up with PG team over email we are not getting response from them because they works in PST hr and i am working in IST hr.

I would suggest you to please raise a support request if there is any emergency.
Support : https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview
Microsoft Azure